# OTP Firebase auth phone-number works fine in debug mode but doesn't work in release mode on android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

After input my real number i got a code to sign-in to my react native app.

- In Debug mode with react-native run:android prompt the code is valid.
- In Release mode which mean the app is already in google play store with no building-
  problem, the code is invalid.

  ```
                            WHY
  ```

???????????????           ??????????????

---

What i did:

- Activating App play integrity and supply the SHA-1 & SHA-256 in firebase project
  Settings that i have got from App signin google play console app from setup-> app-
  integrity.
- in addition i have add/relate on Integrity API the suitable Google Cloud project.

---> Result :
There is no effect - nothing happend or changed the code still not valid in release mode.

what can i do .

please help me.